# Firebase do not report ‘ad_click’ and ‘ad_impression’ events when I use the newest example of firebase-quickstart-ios/admob

Tags: ios, firebase, admob

By using Firebase DebugView, other auto events like "user_engagement", "first_open_time" are reported, but the ‘ad_click’ and ‘ad_impression’ events are not reported.

I check the Prerequisites of "Mobile Ads performance".
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7378163?hl=en

I am using the iOS SDK
The latest admob code example from https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios

I also link the admob app to firebase.

Comment: I also reproduce it on latest android SDK v11.0.0

Comment: Yes, I tried the android SDK v11.0.0. There is no ‘ad_click’ and ‘ad_impression’ events report.

Comment: I'm also unable to see those events. However I see other company receive them. I followed everything from here https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7378163?hl=en. Using the latest 11.0.2 sdk version. Also in release notes https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android you can see 'The following events is now reserved as part of the integration of Analytics with AdMob' ad_click...

Answer (score 0):

To automatically track the 'ad_click' and 'ad_impression' events, the version should be 7.20.0.